# Unable to do the CPI to Orca whirlpool program after obtaining its interface via solang

Tags: anchor, spl-token, cpi, solang

**Description**

We are unable to correctly finalize the call to the Orca whirlpool program fork after we have obtained the whirlpool interface via the `solang idl whirlpool.json` command.

When doing the CPI, we have tried to analyze how the whirlpool SDK calls the needed function, and the assembled data seem to match with what we have passed into the function.

In brief, the CPI we are calling is this one:
https://github.com/valory-xyz/autonolas-tokenomics-solana/blob/a1676ba93a7da2f0da44d32647752b76ac8ae1ae/solidity/nft_token.sol#L207-L224

The `solana idl`-obtained whirlpool interface is located here:
https://github.com/valory-xyz/autonolas-tokenomics-solana/blob/integration/solidity/interfaces/whirlpool.sol

The originating script code is located here:
https://github.com/valory-xyz/autonolas-tokenomics-solana/blob/a1676ba93a7da2f0da44d32647752b76ac8ae1ae/tests/nft_token.ts#L328-L362

**To Reproduce**

Steps to reproduce the behavior:

1. What ledger are you using: Solana
2. Solidity source: https://github.com/valory-xyz/autonolas-tokenomics-solana/blob/integration/solidity/nft_token.sol
3. Client code: https://github.com/valory-xyz/autonolas-tokenomics-solana/blob/integration/tests/nft_token.ts
4. Solang version number: 0.3.3
5. What behavior are you seeing? We are getting the `'Program GUGGHzwC8wEKY3g7QS38YmoS8t5Q2faWAGAfxDK2bXbb failed: Access violation in unknown section at address 0xa of size 32'` error
6. What behavior did you expect? The function to complete the CPI call correctly.

Please read the main README in order to reproduce the exact behavior:
https://github.com/valory-xyz/autonolas-tokenomics-solana/tree/integration

In order to see the expected behavior, the following lines can be uncommented:
https://github.com/valory-xyz/autonolas-tokenomics-solana/blob/a1676ba93a7da2f0da44d32647752b76ac8ae1ae/tests/nft_token.ts#L227-L260

When calling the decreaseLiquidity() function via the whirlpool SDK, we are seeing the following data formed:

```
[
...
    programId: PublicKey [PublicKey(whirLbMiicVdio4qvUfM5KAg6Ct8VwpYzGff3uctyCc)] {
      _bn: <BN: e03685f8e909053e458121c66f5a76aedc7706aa11c82f8aa952a8f2b7879a9>
    },
    data: <Buffer a0 26 d0 6f 68 5b 2c 01 ef f0 ae 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 aa f1 95 02 00 00 00 00 b8 52 2d 00 00 00 00 00>
  }
]
```

We can then state that the decreaseLiquidity() selector is correctly created by the `solang idl whirlpool.json` execution as it matches here:
https://github.com/valory-xyz/autonolas-tokenomics-solana/blob/a1676ba93a7da2f0da44d32647752b76ac8ae1ae/solidity/interfaces/whirlpool.sol#L192-L193

We have also tried to just encode the data into the set of bytes to follow the SDK output, and those lines are listed here:
https://github.com/valory-xyz/autonolas-tokenomics-solana/blob/a1676ba93a7da2f0da44d32647752b76ac8ae1ae/solidity/nft_token.sol#L221-L223

However, we've got the same error result.

**Versions**

1. Version of Solang (v0.3.3)
2. Version of Solana (solana-cli 1.17.7 (src:fca44b78; feat:3073089885, client:SolanaLabs))
3. Version of Anchor (anchor-cli 0.29.0)

**Source code**

The code is located here: https://github.com/valory-xyz/autonolas-tokenomics-solana/tree/integration

[image: Two instructions are executed, and failing on the CPI one]